# Change Text of Textblock in controltemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list of items which a user can select and I would like to add an explanation text. So far I have this code

```
<TabItem Name="TabItem02" Header="">
<ListBox Name="listBox01" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Multiple" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <CheckBox Margin="5,2" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </CheckBox>
                            <Expander Header="Explanation" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                            </Expander>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBoxItem Name="List1Item01" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <ListBoxItem Name="List1Item02" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <ListBoxItem Name="List1Item03" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <ListBoxItem Name="List1Item04" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <ListBoxItem Name="List1Item05" IsEnabled="False"/>
</ListBox>
</TabItem>
```

And at the moment I am changing the content of each `ListBox` through a ressourcefile with this code-behind

```
foreach (ListBox listBox in ListBoxes)
{
            foreach (ListBoxItem item in listBox.Items) item.Content = resourceManager.GetString(item.Name);
}
```

I would like to change the text of the second `TextBlock` (the one in the `Expander`) according to the `ListBoxItem` it belongs to as easy as the `ListBox` content itself through the ressourcefile. I would prefer not to create a separate `Expander` + `TextBlock` for each `ListBoxItem` with a separate name.

So if anyone has a solution for my problem, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: You're doing it in a wrong way. Try [MVVM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern), it would make the things much easier. In short, you may bind `ListBox.ItemsSource` to something like `ObservableCollection<MyItemType>` and simply manage the collection while control will observe the changes and update itself automatically. Also probably you'll need `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation for a data item containing class. While it sound complicated it's easier to use. And yes, it will solve the problem.

Comment: You may open my profile, there's a lot of guide-style WPF+MVVM-related answers. Some of them can be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i havent tried mvvm yet and for this simple project i would like not to change the whole architecture and basically start from scratch and learn this new thing, although you say its quite easy. I am going to look into this some other day, but for now i would like to keep it simple for me.